# Don't understand why getting an AttributeError for one XML field but not others

Tags: python, xml, csv

Below is my code to convert xml to csv. `empId`, `fullName` are converting as expected, but cannot get city of `currentAddress` working. What I am doing wrong?

If I use currentAddress in emp_head.append it does nothing, if I use `"city"`, then it errors out with the error message `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'`.

XML:

```xml
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns2:exportEmpData xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.example.com/">
<emplist>
<empId>6029</empId>
<fullName>Justin Clark</fullName>
<currentAddress houseNumber="14" street="Lepanto" city="Barcelona"/>
</emplist>
<emplist>
<empId>6078</empId>
<fullName>Jose Domingo</fullName>
<currentAddress houseNumber="48" street="Gran Via" city="Madrid"/>
</emplist>
</ns2:exportEmpData>
```

My code:

```
import xml
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:/emp/emplist.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

Emp_data = open('C:/emp/emplist.csv', 'wb')

csvwriter = csv.writer(Emp_data)
emp_head = []

count = 0

for member in root.findall('emplist'):
emp_nodes = []
if count == 0:
    empId = member.find('empId').tag
    emp_head.append(empId)
    fullName = member.find('fullName').tag
    emp_head.append(fullName)
    currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').tag
    emp_head.append(currentAddress)
            csvwriter.writerow(emp_head)
    count = count + 1

empId = member.find('empId').text
emp_nodes.append(empId)
fullName = member.find('fullName').text
emp_nodes.append(fullName)
currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').text
emp_nodes.append(currentAddress)
csvwriter.writerow(emp_nodes)
Emp_data.close()
```

I need to convert 3 fields from the above xml:

```
empId,fullName,city
6029,Justin Clark,Barcelona
6078,Jose Domingo,Madrid
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').attrib.get('city')
```

Getting the value of `text` is incorrect in this context.

Comment: That works like a treat. Thanks. However, I got another issue with the above xml. Not every employee receives "currentAddress" element. How to make it optional?